# What is the origin of the "my" variable/method/et-al in didactic materials?

Tags: history, programming

I think back to many tutorials and code snippets in which I have seen variables, functions, and files with "my" or "my_" prepended. What is the origin of this convention?

Comment: AFAIK, Microsoft started that childishness with "My Computer" in Windows 95.

Comment: The *origin* of this convention is English grammar providing possessive pronouns to indicate the desired semantics in a mnemonic way. Perhaps, you mean "what was the earliest known publication using that convention"? If so, please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: Another coding tic I've seen is for code comments to use the first-person plural, e.g., `// we have to close X before opening Y because...`, and so forth.

Comment: maybe so it doesn't conflict with built-in objects of the language? I remember defining MyString, MyFile...

Comment: Editorial ‘we’ is pretty standard, it’s nothing exclusive to code comments.

Comment: Typically a programming book tells you a concept such as variables or functions and then gives an example how you can define your own variables or functions so it makes it logical to name them my_variable or my_function in the examples.

Comment: It's not a convention, it's just the author of that tutorial telling you that this is your/their own version of it. It's often used to differentiate a standard library function from your own implementation (`strlen` vs. `my_strlen`)

Comment: The correct names to use for example variables are 'foo', 'bar', and 'mumblefrotz'.

Comment: @another-dave Meh, eventually you’ll run out of nonsense words. The ‘my’ convention may sound silly, but it’s at least very legible.

Comment: @user3840170 I never said or even implied it was exclusive, but enjoy your upvotes.

Comment: @another-dave I don't know where mumblefrotz comes from and I've never heard it before. The pseudo-standard for the third [metasyntactic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) in the sequence is "baz"... but thanks for making me refresh my memory. I've been skipping over "qux" and going straight to "quux" for number 4 for years. Likewise, for Python, I was using the *de facto* standard ones incorrectly by skipping from "spam" to "eggs" without going through "ham".

Comment: [mumblefrotz](https://mumblefrotz.org/) is adaptable; it's both a metasyntactic variable and commentary.

Comment: I first remember seeing the my variables in Microsoft's MFC 1.0 documentation in 1992/93.

Comment: Not an answer, because it doesn't actually answer the question: The "my_" convention, now considered something of an anti-pattern, was common back in the day.  It's akin to Hungarian notation, where you use naming conventions to give the reader clues about a variable's purpose or type.  It was commonly used to create temporary variables that would shadow or conflict with the name of an entity that is in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Origin? ...I think that comes from simple human interest in taking topics out of the specific and into a more general context, in that, at least when I do this myself (which is mostly every time I share ANY code in a public forum), I, as the old Dragnet TV program used to say "change the names to protect the innocent." It's not any more complicated than that!

This is ESPECIALLY true of people asking questions in the Stack Exchange community: MOST of us work in environments where whatever we're working on is at least SOMEWHAT concerned about privacy; we don't want to inadvertently, much less intentionally, share information that we may very well have non-disclosure agreements covering! This could be code we're writing for a client or for a corporation, etc...

Don't over-think it!

Comment: This is asking about a naming convention found within documentation, which is generally public, so the tangent about NDAs is mostly irrelevant. And the rest is [armchair speculation](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1031/15334).

Comment: @user3840170 Speculation? Surely. But, first, you apparently overlooked my initial paragraph and focused on the second. And ... where do you think documentation comes from? Hint: Mostly it's from engineers / code developers who actually perform the work, and, even when written by professional writers they get a LOT of documentation material from engineers who provide them examples... Speaking from experience, I am _not_ wrong, however, it's SURELY speculative what "origins" were. And, I directly said the NDA issue often applies to Stack Exchange-like sites.